# setAdapter в Navigation Drawer при создании списка пунктов меню приводит к ошибке

Tags: java, android, listview, android-layout, android-navigation-drawer

Ошибка:
**FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                         Process: com.example.mustngo.newsp, PID: 1713
                                                                         android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class android.widget.TextView**

```html
public abstract class SingleFragmentActivity extends FragmentActivity{
    protected abstract Fragment createFragment();
    private String[] mPlanetTitles;
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ListView mDrawerList;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.drawer_layout);

        mPlanetTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.screen_array);
        mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);
        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer);
        // Set the adapter for the list view
        mDrawerList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                R.layout.drawer_list_item,mPlanetTitles));
        // Set the list's click listener
       // mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());


        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        Fragment fragment = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.fragmentContainer);
        if (fragment == null){
            fragment = createFragment();
            fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragmentContainer, fragment).commit();
        }
    }
}
```

drawer_layout.xml

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/drawer"
    >

    <include layout="@layout/activity_fragment"/>


    <!-- The navigation drawer -->

    <ListView android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:background="#111"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

drawer_list_item.xml

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/label"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/activated_background"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:minHeight="?attr/listPreferredItemHeightSmall"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    android:text="test"
    android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас ошибка в разметке элемента списка на второй строке. Там у вас `id`. И т.к. вы используете системный адаптер, скорее всего `ID` надо прописать аналогичный системной разметке. Т.е. попробуйте изменить его на

```
@android:id/text1 //или  @android:id/text
```

Если не помогло - попробуйте системную разметку вместо вашей поставить -

```
android.R.layout.simple_list_item
```

Comment: ЮрийСПб, большое спасибо за замечание. В программе исправил, но ошибка осталась та же. Так же подправил код в вопросе.

Comment: @mustango, не вижу исправлений. Если не помогло - попробуйте системную разметку вместо вашей поставить - `android.R.layout.simple_list_item`

Comment: ЮрийСПб, спасибо еще раз. Поправил с последними замечаниями, с системной разметкой все работает. Данный вопрос решен.